# operation not allowed when the object is closed when running more advanced query

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

When I try to run a more advanced SQL query on an ASP page I get this error:

> operation not allowed when the object is closed

When I run this code it's working:

```
...
sql = "SELECT distinct team FROM tbl_teams"
rs.open sql, conndbs, 1, 1
...
```

But when I run this code (and this code is working if I run it in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio), I get the error...

```
...
sql = "DECLARE     @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),     @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),     @orderby nvarchar(max),     @currentYear varchar(4)  select @currentYear = cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4))  select @cols   = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(year([datefrom]))            from tbl_teams            group by year([datefrom])            order by year([datefrom]) desc             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')         ,1,1,'')  select @orderby = 'ORDER BY ['+cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) + '] desc'  set @query = 'SELECT team, Won = [1],                 Lost=[2], Draw = [3]' + @cols + ', Total             from             (               select                 team,                 new_col,                 total                from               (                 select team,                   dt = year([datefrom]),                   result,                   total = count(*) over(partition by team)                 from tbl_teams               ) d               cross apply               (                 select ''dt'', dt union all                 select ''result'', case when dt = '+@currentYear+' then result end               ) c (old_col_name, new_col)             ) x             pivot             (                 count(new_col)                 for new_col in ([1], [2], [3],' + @cols + ')             ) p '+ @orderby  exec sp_executesql @query"
rs.open sql, conndbs, 1, 1
...
```

This is a better overview of the query:

```
DECLARE 
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @orderby nvarchar(max),
    @currentYear varchar(4)

select @currentYear = cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4))

select @cols 
  = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(year([datefrom])) 
           from tbl_teams
           group by year([datefrom])
           order by year([datefrom]) desc
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @orderby = 'ORDER BY ['+cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) + '] desc'

set @query = 'SELECT team, Won = [1], 
                Lost=[2], Draw = [3]' + @cols + ', Total
            from 
            (
              select 
                team,
                new_col,
                total  
              from
              (
                select team, 
                  dt = year([datefrom]),
                  result,
                  total = count(*) over(partition by team)
                from tbl_teams
              ) d
              cross apply
              (
                select ''dt'', dt union all
                select ''result'', case when dt = '+@currentYear+' then result end
              ) c (old_col_name, new_col)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(new_col)
                for new_col in ([1], [2], [3],' + @cols + ')
            ) p '+ @orderby

exec sp_executesql @query
```

Do I need to run the query on another way or what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Three words for you `SET NOCOUNT ON`, without it `ADODB` will see the count as a separate closed recordset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common problem caused by row counts being interpreted as output from a Stored Procedure when using `ADODB` with SQL Server.

To avoid this remember to set

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

in your Stored Procedure this will stop ADODB returning a closed recordset, or if for whatever reason you don't want to do this (not sure why as you can always use `@@ROWCOUNT` to pass the row count back), you can use

```vb
'Return the next recordset, which will be the result of the Stored Procedure, not 
'the row count generated when SET NOCOUNT OFF (default).
Set rs = rs.NextRecordset()
```

which returns the next `ADODB.Recordset` if ADODB has detected one being returned by the Stored Procedure (might be best to check `rs.State <> adStateClosed` when dealing with multiple ADODB.Recordset objects).