# ADODB.Recordset: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, adodb

I receive the error - ADODB.Recordset: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed. when using a multiple table sql statement.

other sql statements (simple ones) I do not receive and error, and I have copied the sql statement into query to verify it works ok in MSSQL from printed out sql variable - and it does return values.

Method

```
sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON;SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;use dbcheck; " &_
"select year([00080020]) as YEAR, month([00080020]) as MONTH,sum(bytesize/1024/1024/1024) as GBStored, count(distinct [0020000d]) " &_
" as FinalCount from tblt t, tbls s, tblf f where" &_
" id1 = _id1 and id2 = _id2file" &_
" and [00080020] is not null" &_
" group by year([00080020]), month([00080020]) order by year([00080020]) desc, month([00080020]) desc"

Dim cndb : Set cndb = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim rsdb: Set rsdb = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
cndb.Provider = "sqloledb"
cndb.Properties("Data Source").Value = "127.0.0.1"
cndb.Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = "master"
cndb.Properties("Integrated Security").Value = "SSPI"

cndb.CursorLocation = 3
cndb.Open
set rsdb = CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
cmd.ActiveConnection = cndb
cmd.CommandType = 1
cmd.CommandText = sql
rsdb.CursorLocation = 3
rsdb.CursorType = 3
rsdb.LockType = 3
Set rsdb = cmd.Execute
    IF Not (rsdb IS Nothing) Then
    rsdb.MoveFirst ** ERRORS OUT HERE
```

Thanks
--------2nd attempt sql is same

```
Dim cndb : Set cndb = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim rsdb: Set rsdb = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cndb.Provider = "sqloledb"
' Set SQLOLEDB connection properties.
cndb.Properties("Data Source").Value = "127.0.0.1"
cndb.Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = "master"

' Windows NT authentication.
cndb.Properties("Integrated Security").Value = "SSPI"

cndb.CommandTimeout=900
cndb.CursorLocation = 3
cndb.Open

rsdb.CursorLocation = 3
rsdb.CursorType = 3
rsdb.LockType = 3
rsdb.Open sql,cndb

rptFile.WriteLine sql
rptFile.WriteLine cndb.State
rptFile.WriteLine rsdb.State

IF Not (rsdb IS Nothing) Then
  If Not rsdb.EOF Then  * Errors out on this line
    rsdb.MoveFirst
```

Comment: have you tried rsb.open ?

Comment: Shouldn't the `ActiveConnection` be *set*, since it's an object reference? `Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cndb`

Comment: I started with rsdb.open, and was playing with other methods.   I changed it back with same issue.  I also tried the cmd.ActiveConnection without any luck either.  Appreciate the ideas to try.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25824266/692942

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35869388/692942

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35313932/692942

Comment: Plenty of reading material there and thats just the ones I've answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're receiving an empty recordset.

```
Set rsdb = cmd.Execute
If Not (rsdb IS Nothing) Then
    rsdb.MoveFirst ** ERRORS OUT HERE
```

You can't *move to first record* if `rsdb.EOF` returns `True`. Try this:

```
Set rsdb = cmd.Execute
If Not (rsdb Is Nothing) Then
    If Not rsdb.EOF Then
        rsdb.MoveFirst
        ...
    End If
End If
```

And then diagnose your query and see if it *actually* returns anything. This might help:

```
Echo sql
```

---

That said, you're setting the recordset's reference 3 times, and discarding the previous reference every time.

```
Dim rsdb: Set rsdb = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

That `Set` statement is superfluous, because...

```
cndb.Open
set rsdb = CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
```

You're setting it again here. But that `Set` statement is *also* superfluous, because...

```
Set rsdb = cmd.Execute
```

That's the only reference assignment that actually needs to happen. The `CursorLocation` and other properties you're setting, are discarded along with the discarded reference. Remove them too.

Comment: I changed over and removed those duplicates you mentioned and put in the if statement for EOF.  Now it errors out on that If Not rsdb.EOF line with same error.   I put in write out for sql - checks out fine and cndb.State=1, rsdb.State=0.

Comment: `Debug.Print` won't work for VBScript use `WScript.Echo`.

Comment: You still going to have the same problem with `If Not (rsdb Is Nothing) Then` because the `ADODB.Recordset` is likely being returned but with a `State` Property of `adStateClosed`.

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue - in the SQL statement I was had
use dbcheck
trying to select it with use statement worked in SQL QUERY ANALYZER - just not in the script, I changed the Initial Catalog to dbcheck and removed the "use" from sql and it worked.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: `USE` to set the DB context is seen as a Closed Recordset by ADODB so you could have called `Set rsdb = rsdb.NextRecordset` to move to the next recordset object which would be your query result.