# Returning values from a stored procedure ASP Classic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I am having a problem to output the results from a stored procedure using SQL Server and ASP Classic. If I have a simple `SELECT` into the procedure, it works fine. But with the code shown here, I get an error.

I have this stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_Teste]
    @data varchar(8)
AS
BEGIN
    --DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempSubs
    
    DECLARE @TempSubs TABLE
                      (
                           PedidoID Int, 
                           NumeroPedido Varchar(20), 
                           SubstituidoPor Varchar(8000)
                      )
    
    INSERT INTO @TempSubs (PedidoID, NumeroPedido, SubstituidoPor) 
        SELECT 
            P.ID, P.NumeroPedido, 
            STRING_AGG(CAST(IPA.Quantidade AS varchar(5)) + 'X ' + Pd.Nome, ', ') + ' por ' + STRING_AGG(CAST(IPA.Quantidade AS varchar(5)) + 'X ' + Pd2.Nome, ', ') AS SubstituidoPor
        FROM 
            Pedidos P, Clientes C, Produtos Pd, ItensPedidosAjustado IPA, Produtos Pd2
        WHERE 
            P.ID = IPA.PedidoId
            AND P.ClienteId = C.ID
            AND Pd.ID = IPA.ProdutoId
            AND Faltante = 1
            AND CONVERT(Date, P.DataPedido, 103) = CONVERT(Date, @data, 103)
            AND (IPA.ProdutoSubstituidoId <> 0)
            AND Pd2.ID = IPA.ProdutoSubstituidoId
            AND ((P.StatusPedido <> 'Pause' AND P.StatusPedido <> 'PULOU ENTREGA' AND P.StatusPedido <> 'Pedido Cancelado') OR P.StatusPedido IS NULL)
        GROUP BY 
            P.ID, P.NumeroPedido, IPA.ProdutoSubstituidoId
    
    SELECT
        (SELECT STRING_AGG(Indisponibilidade, ', ') 
         FROM @TempIndis A 
         WHERE A.PedidoID = P.ID) AS Indisponibilidade,
        (SELECT STRING_AGG(SubstituidoPor, ', ') 
         FROM @TempSubs A 
         WHERE A.PedidoID = P.ID) AS Substituicao        
    FROM 
        Pedidos P, Clientes C, ItensPedidosAjustado IPA
    WHERE 
        P.ID = IPA.PedidoId
        AND P.ClienteId = C.ID
        AND Faltante = 1
        AND CONVERT(Date, P.DataPedido, 103) = CONVERT(Date, @data, 103)
        AND ((P.StatusPedido <> 'Pause' AND P.StatusPedido <> 'PULOU ENTREGA' AND P.StatusPedido <> 'Pedido Cancelado') OR P.StatusPedido IS NULL)
        AND P.PedidoCancelado = 0
    GROUP BY 
        P.ID, P.NumeroPedido, C.Nome, C.Email, P.TipoAssinatura
    ORDER BY 
        numeropedido
END
```

and this code in ASP Classic

```
 db_conn = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=xxxx;Database=BaseGaia;Uid=sqlserver;Pwd=xxxxx;"
    set conn = server.createobject("adodb.connection")
    set Cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    '-------------------------------------------------------
    conn.open (db_conn)
    '-------------------------------------------------------
    set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")  
    sSQL = "EXEC Sp_Teste @data = '20210301'"
    
    set rs = conn.execute (sSQL)

    response.write rs.eof
```

I get this error:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'
> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
> /Atendimento/testestoreprocedure.asp, line 18

Comment: Don't you need to open the connection first? Please don't use `,` join suntax, it's been deprecated for many years

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

By default, SQL Server returns [`DONE_IN_PROC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (rowcount) messages after `INSERT` statements, which ADO classic returns a closed/empty result sets. These must be consumed by invoking the `NextRecordset` method before the `SELECT` query results are available.

To avoid the extra coding, make a habit of specifying [`SET NOCOUNT ON;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in stored procedures to suppress those unwanted results. Add that to the beginning of the proc code to avoid the error.

Comment: This question has been done to death, seriously why do we need [another duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25824266/692942) when there are [already so many](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03DNKyzWjGXsKP1if5CAkdG1i4QYg%3A1614768582657&ei=xmk_YIHIJ4jdgQabiYL4DQ&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+operation+not+allowed+when+the+object+is+closed&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+operation+not+allowed+when+the+object+is+closed&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANQmxFYiiZghidoAXACeACAAVCIAZgKkgECMjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiBw43e-ZPvAhWIbsAKHZuEAN8Q4dUDCA0)?

Comment: @user692942, I did a cursory search using Google and I did not find answers on the first couple of results that called out `DONE_IN_PROC` messages and that the issue can also be handled by the client code. Completely agree the question is all to common 20 years after MS released the sucky ADO classic API.